# What is the Failed requests meaning in ApacheBench?

Tags: linux, server, apachebench

I am doing load testing in project..I have sent 10000 request using below comment in linux `ab -r  -n 10000 -c 1000 https://yyy.com?data="{\"email\":\"asd.v@yy.com\",\"device_type\":\"1\",\"device_token\":\"qweqwqwqwqw\",\"device_id\":\"1\",\"password\":\"123123123\",\"confirm_password\":\"123123123\",\"name\":\"eet\",\"language_code\":\"en\"}"`

I got  below response form ApacheBench tool

```
Benchmarking Ip (be patient)
Completed 1000 requests
Completed 2000 requests
Completed 3000 requests
Completed 4000 requests
Completed 5000 requests
Completed 6000 requests
Completed 7000 requests
Completed 8000 requests
Completed 9000 requests
Completed 10000 requests
Finished 10000 requests


Server Software:        nginx/1.8.1
Server Hostname:        xxx
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          //yyy.com?data="{\"email\":\"asd.v@yy.com\",\"device_type\":\"1\",\"device_token\":\"qweqwqwqwqw\",\"device_id\":\"1\",\"password\":\"123123123\",\"confirm_password\":\"123123123\",\"name\":\"eet\",\"language_code\":\"en\"}

Document Length:        109 bytes
Concurrency Level:      1000
Time taken for tests:   481.304 seconds
Complete requests:      10000
Failed requests:        6509
   (Connect: 0, Receive: 811, Length: 9047, Exceptions: 811)
Write errors:           0
Non-2xx responses:      4607
Total transferred:      4689016 bytes
HTML transferred:       2317894 bytes
Requests per second:    20.78 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       48130.375 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       48.130 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          9.51 [Kbytes/sec] received

 Connection Times (ms)
                min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:         0 5343 13278.2     12   63181
Processing:     11 39423 31238.8  31284  183489
Waiting:         0 31140 21264.0  29497  143154
Total:        185 44765 34795.6  35541  214551

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
   50%  35541
   66%  46401
   75%  58835
   80%  67056
   90%  95570
   95%  127218
   98%  127317
   99%  164858
   100%  214551 (longest request)
```

My question is how to find 6509 request are failed request.
May i change any server setup?
Or 
May change any coding ?